# Show that if $P(H | E) > P(H)$, then $P (H' | E) < P(H')$ using only probability rules and not using frequentist way of proving this

Tags: probability

I am having trouble showing this proof since I got from $P(H | E) > P(H)$,
\begin{align}
\frac{P (H \cap E)}{P (E)} &> P (H)  \\[5pt]
P (H \cap E) &> P (H) P(E)  \\
P(H \cap E) &> P(E) - P(E)P (H')
\end{align}
However I get stuck at this point and I am not sure how to continue. Can someone explain in detail the steps I need to do to get to  $P (H' | E) < P(H')$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward if you use the rule that $P(X) = 1 - P(X')$

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(H | E)&> P(H) \\
1 - P(H' | E) &> 1 - P(H') \\ 
-P(H' | E) &> - P(H') \\
\therefore P(H' | E) &< P(H')
\end{aligned}
$$

Note that when we multiply by $-1$ in the last step, we switch the direction of the inequality